# How to parse through a csv file by awk?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

Actually I have csv file with suppose 20 headers and they have corresponding values for those headers in the next row for a particular record.
Example : Source file

```
Age,Name,Salary
25,Anand,32000
```

I want my output file to be in this format.
Example : Output file

```
Age
25
Name
Anand
Salary
32000
```

So for doing this which awk/grep/sed command to be used?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Is your input just 2 lines, or do you have multiple pairs of header/data lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i;next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[i] RS $i}' file
Age
25
Name
Anand
Salary
32000
```

First `for` loop store the header in array `a`
Second `for` loop prints header from array `a` with corresponding data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { split($0, headers); next } { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { print headers[i]; print $i } }' filename
```

That is

```
NR == 1 {                       # in the first line
  split($0, headers)            # remember the headers
  next                          # do nothing else
}
{                               # after that:
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {    # for all fields:
    print headers[i]            # print the corresponding header
    print $i                    # followed by the field
  }
}
```

**Addendum:** Obligatory, crazy sed solution (not recommended for productive use; written for fun, not profit):

```
sed 's/$/,/; 1 { h; d; }; G; :a s/\([^,]*\),\([^\n]*\n\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\2\4\n\3\n\1/; ta; s/^\n\n//' filename
```

That works as follows:

```
s/$/,/         # Add a comma to all lines for more convenient processing
1 { h; d; }    # first line: Just put it in the hold buffer
G              # all other lines: Append hold bufffer (header fields) to the
               # pattern space
:a             # jump label for looping

               # isolate the first fields from the data and header lines,
               # move them to the end of the pattern space
s/\([^,]*\),\([^\n]*\n\)\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\2\4\n\3\n\1/
ta             # do this until we got them all
s/^\n\n//      # then remove the two newlines that are left as an artifact of
               # the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk 4.* for 2D arrays:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[NR][1];split($0,a[NR])} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) print a[j][i]}' file
Age
25
Name
Anand
Salary
32000
```

In general to transpose rows and columns:

```
$ cat file
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
41 42 43
```

with GNU awk:

```
$ awk '{a[NR][1];split($0,a[NR])} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) printf "%s%s", a[j][i], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)}' file
11 21 31 41
12 22 32 42
13 23 33 43
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR][i]=$i} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) printf "%s%s", a[j][i], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)}' file
11 21 31 41
12 22 32 42
13 23 33 43
```